# Why Function returning None in Python Output

Tags: python, function

I want to know why the following two codes are returning None in Python output? Can somebody help me writing both codes correctly separately and tell me what's causing it to return None and explain please? I need the following output: Pay 498.75

```
# 1st Code - Returning None 
def computepay(int1,int2):
    try: 
        h = float(int1)
        r = float(int2)
    except:
        print ("Error, please enter a numeric input")
        quit()
    if h >= 40:
        pay1 = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5

        #print(pay1)
    else:
        pay2 = h * r
        #print( pay2)
p = computepay(45,10)
print("Pay",p)
```

```
# 2nd Code - Returning None 
def computepay(int1,int2):
    try: 
        h = float(int1)
        r = float(int2)
    except:
        print ("Error, please enter a numeric input")
        quit()
    if h >= 40:
        pay1 = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5

        print(pay1)
    else:
        pay2 = h * r
        print( pay2)
print("Pay",computepay(45,10.5))
#print("Pay",p)
```

Comment: I don't see a return statement

Comment: What do you think should be returned, and why/how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a return statement in order for python to know what to return:

```
def computepay(int1,int2):
    try: 
        h = float(int1)
        r = float(int2)
    except:
        print("Error, please enter a numeric input")
        quit()
    if h >= 40:
        return 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5
    else:
        return h * r
p = computepay(45,10.5)
print("Pay",p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to use *return*.
 A function give back except the print only what u want to return. So when u call a function to print it or to use however u want .... u take what u return
so your code must be

```
def computepay(int1,int2):
    try: 
        h = float(int1)
        r = float(int2)
    except:
        print ("Error, please enter a numeric input")
        quit()
    if h >= 40:
        pay1 = 40 * r + (h - 40) * r * 1.5      # u can use return directly here
        return pay1

        print(pay1)                             # print helps only for your test
    else:
        pay2 = h * r                            # same here u can use directly return h*r
        print( pay2)
        return pay2

print("Pay",computepay(45,10.5))
```